# WAMP Phpmyadmin Login Still Don't Display

Tags: authentication, phpmyadmin, wamp

Okay, I know it may sound *stupid* but I really need your opinions or suggestions about something. A computer has an **older WAMP version** (5 1.7.0) installed in it (*I'm not the one who installed it*) and running on Windows XP. Whenever I go to its Phpmyadmin page, it automatically gives me access to anything what are in it. That's a security hole that must be solved. **I want it to ask me or prompt a login page** first. I still have no success from the following steps that I've tried:

- I have set the username as `root` and the password as
  `samplepass` from the **Priveleges** section in the Phpmyadmin page - Still no success!
- I also modified the `config.inc.php` file. I put the said password in `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']` and changed the "*cookie*" as "*config*" in `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']` - Still no success!
- Already restarted the connection of all WAMP services after the changes made - Still no success!
- I also cleared the histories, caches, cookies, etc. in the browsers just incase - Still no success!

One thing I've noticed is that the file has no `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword']` nor `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPasswordRoot']` in it. I tried including that into the file and providing it the value as "YES" but still, no login page is displaying.

I don't want to reinstall the WAMP or install new one. I'm afraid to destroy what was already there. So what do you think why the login page is still not displaying? Am I forgetting something or missed to do? (*Sorry for sometimes I'm forgetful*).

Comment: have you restart wamp after doing changes in config.inc.php ?

Comment: Yes I did but the login page is still not displaying. I dunno why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, just after trying the things out again with still no success, I came up with this:

- I changed back the value of `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']` from "*config*" to "*cookie*"
- Then I added a random text value for `$cfg['blowfish_secret']`

After the (2) changes I made, I restarted the all the services again and poof! **Login page is now displaying!** But I'm still confused why my first tries didn't work. I'm not a *know-it-all* person about this particular area and sure there's more things to know about database thing. That's all.

Comment: The big question is why, if the value was initially set to 'cookie', it wasn't prompting you initially. About why the other things; I wonder if you may have changed the root password corresponding to a different host -- most systems have several 'root' users with different values for the host field, these are not the same user of course. I did not expect auth_type 'config' to prompt you for a password, as explained in the manual, likewise the `AllowNoPassword` and `AllowNoPasswordRoot` fields don't control that, either. But all in all, glad it works now.